# change the default delivery of messages to an offline PST file in outlook

Tags: outlook

Users of Outlook change the default delivery of messages to an offline PST file.
This results in users losing remote access to their e-mail through OWA, mobile devices,
and other desktops. It also breaks the ability of nightly backup of exchange to include all incoming e-mail. is there's any way to prevent the user to change the default data file or make the OST the default data file in each outlook when user run the outlook?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you cannot change the location of delivered emails if the default account is an Exchange account.  So how are these users redirecting?  With Rules?

Otherwise, to change the default data file you will need to use Redemption:

http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdostore.htm

Comment: thank you for your answer, I did it using registry. :)

Comment: So you chose a method that's not documented and unsupported. Good luck with that!

Answer (score 0):

old days I wrote default delivery changer (Outlookdeliverychanger.exe) for outlook versions 2003/2007/2010. I can post Executable if you need it. 
here is source repo https://github.com/MrdUkk/outlookdeliverychanger

Comment: yes It would be really helpful form you thank you so much appreciate your help if you do.

Comment: Here 2 Exe files (for 64bit outlook and for 32 bit). thats because MAPI interfaces is arch-dependent). I didn't use undocumented feautures to write this, only public information. Feel free to contact me if you interested "under the hood" http://www.sendspace.com/file/16oic1